# Rails view - user enters minutes, we save seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, view

I have a simple text_field in my form where a user enters a time in minutes, i.e. 60.

How can I multiply that number by 60 before saving the form, such that the database stores the number in seconds?

Then, how do I reverse that and show the field in minutes on another view?

Thank you!

Comment: Do u have any programming experience?
Think before asking. Better say work on basics. Dont try to cover number of pages of book. Better you try to cover topics in better way

Comment: That wasn't particularly helpful piemesons. People new to the language may have simple questions from your perspective, but their confusion may be due to trying to get a concept they read about to work, rather than for a lack of diligence or 'thinking' on their part. Thank you to Corroded for the helpful reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, multiply the variable by 60 before calling the save function of your model

To show that, in your view or in your controller's show function just divide the number by 60.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a method in you model called "time_in_seconds" that multiply your time and stores it in the correct place.

It should be more DRY since you'll have access to your model in every controller/view and will have the same method for all